# ZODB commit stuck and make my whole application to freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, zodb

Today I found a bug on my python application using ZODB.
Trying to find why my application freezes up, I figured that ZODB was the cause.

Setting the logging to debug, it seem that when commiting, that ZODB would find 2 connections and then start freezing.

```
INFO:ZEO.ClientStorage:('127.0.0.1', 8092) Connected to storage: ('localhost', 8092)
DEBUG:txn.140661100980032:new transaction
DEBUG:txn.140661100980032:commit
DEBUG:ZODB.Connection:Committing savepoints of size 1858621925
DEBUG:discord.gateway:Keeping websocket alive with sequence 59.
DEBUG:txn.140661100980032:commit <Connection at 7fee2d080fd0>
DEBUG:txn.140661100980032:commit <Connection at 7fee359e5cc0>
```

As I'm a ZODB beginner, any idea on a how to solve / how to dig deeper ?

It seems to be related to concurrent commits.

I believed that opening a new connection would initiate a dedicated transaction manager, but this is not the case. While initiating a new connection without specifying a transaction manager, the local one (shared with other connections on the thread) is used.

My code:

```
async def get_connection():
    return ZEO.connection(8092)

async def _message_db_init_aux(self, channel, after=None, before=None):
    connexion = await get_connection()
    root = connexion.root()

    messages = await some_function_which_return_a_list()

    async for message in messages:
        # If author.id doesn't exist on the data, let's initiate it as a Tree
        if message.author.id not in root.data: # root.data is a BTrees.OOBTree.BTree()
            root.data[message.author.id] = BTrees.OOBTree.BTree()

        # Message is a defined classed inherited from persistant.Persistant
        root.data[message.author.id][message.id] = Message(message.id, message.author.id, message.created_at)

    transaction.commit()
    connexion.close()
```

Comment: Why are you comitting a nearly 2GB transaction? I think that’s much more likely to be the problem here.

Comment: Please do include enough code for us to be able to reproduce the problem. If you are creating additional connections in a thread yourself, please detail how you do that.

Comment: Initial post edited with code as requested

Comment: Isn't that the *corrected* code? You'd want to post the code that caused the problem to begin with.

Comment: Code editied. Indeed, it was the corrected one's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't re-use transaction managers across connections. Each connection has its own transaction manager, *use that*.

Your code currently creates the connection, then commits. Rather than create the connection, ask the database to create a transaction manager for you, which then manages its own connection. The transaction manager can be used as a *context manager*, meaning that changes to the database are automatically committed when the context ends.

Moreover, by using `ZEO.connection()` *for each transaction*, you are forcing ZEO to create a complete new client object, with a fresh cache and connection pool. By using `ZEO.DB()` instead, and caching the result, a single client is created from which connections can be pooled and reused, and with a local cache to speed up transactions.

I'd alter the code to:

```
def get_db():
    """Access the ZEO database client.

    The database client is cached to take advantage of caching and connection pooling

    """
    db = getattr(get_db, 'db', None)
    if db is None:
        get_db.db = db = ZEO.DB(8092)
    return db

async def _message_db_init_aux(self, channel, after=None, before=None):
    with self.get_db().transaction() as conn:
        root = conn.root()

        messages = await some_function_which_return_a_list()

        async for message in messages:
            # If author.id doesn't exist on the data, let's initiate it as a Tree
            if message.author.id not in root.data: # root.data is a BTrees.OOBTree.BTree()
                root.data[message.author.id] = BTrees.OOBTree.BTree()

            # Message is a defined classed inherited from persistant.Persistant
            root.data[message.author.id][message.id] = Message(
                message.id, message.author.id, message.created_at
            )
```

The `.transaction()` method on the database object creates a new connection under the hood, the moment the context is entered (`with` causing `__enter__` to be called), and when the `with` block ends the transaction is committed and the connection is released to the pool again.

Note that I used a synchronous `def get_db()` method; the call signatures on the ZEO client code are entirely synchronous. They are safe to call from asynchronous code because *under the hood*, the implementation uses `asyncio` throughout, using callbacks and tasks on the same loop, and actual I/O is deferred to separate tasks.

Answer (score 0):

When not precised, the local transaction manager is used.
If you open multiple connections on the same thread, you have to precise the transaction manager you want to use. By default

```
 transaction.commit()
```

is the local transaction manager.

```
 connection.transaction.manager.commit()
```

will  use the transaction manager dedicated to the transaction (and not the local one).

For more informations, check http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/guide/transactions-and-threading.html

Comment: You really want to use a context manager if you can to create the extra connection and manage the transaction for that connection.